# How to create X number of endpoints?

Tags: asterisk

In `pjsip.conf` I have each endpoint defined as follows:

```
[my-endpoint](!)
type=endpoint
context=default
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
transport=simpletrans


[1234](my-endpoint)
auth=auth1234
aors=1234

[auth1234](auth-userpass)
password=<super_secret_password>
username=1234

[1234](aor-single-reg)
contact=sip:1234@<hostname>
```

This is fine for one or two endpoint but if I want to add 10s or 100s it becomes tedious to manage. I was hoping to find a solution that would either allow me to create some sort of wildcard endpoint like `123X` which would create endpoints `1230-1239` but that doesn't seem to exist. Or even something that would parameterize the creation of endpoint would be better, like

```
[my-endpoint](!)
type=endpoint
...
endpoint/1234 = <password>
endpoint/1235 = <password>
endpoint/1236 = <password>
```

I'm not finding much aside from a deprecated `autocreatepeer` setting which is way too insecure for what I'm trying to do. Does something like this exist or am I stuck with just having to 10 lines of configs for each endpoint.

Comment: Most people have their own intermediate layer in place that generates Asterisk config files for them. You should set up your business logic, and then write a program to generate the configs for you from that. Providers aren't manually creating configs by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **REALTIME** mechanism and put endpoints in the database.

No, you can't use patterns in endpoint. You are already using templates and that's all.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Setting+up+PJSIP+Realtime

Answer (score 0):

@Woodsy
I also had same Problem which I solved with below methods:
(May not be the exact Solution you are looking for)

**Method 1:**
I made a utility in Java having create and delete APIs to automatically write and delete the Endpoints in pjsip.conf Used Template Rendering for endpoint properties.

**Method 2:**
I created some Common Contexts for PJSIP-Peer Properties, AOR, AUTH used with peers. It made my Endpoint each having 24+ lines to just 8.

```
[common-pjsip-peer](!)
type=endpointcontext=IBD-context
transport=transport-wss
disallow=all
allow=opus,alaw,ulaw
webrtc=yes
max_audio_streams=1
rtp_timeout=30
rtp_keepalive=10
direct_media=yes
moh_passthrough=yes
media_encryption=sdes
media_encryption_optimistic=yes

[common-webrtc-aor](!)
type=aor
max_contacts=1
qualify_frequency=30
qualify_timeout=15.0
remove_existing=yes
remove_unavailable=yes
maximum_expiration=36000

[common-auth](!)
type=auth
auth_type=userpass


;**Actual Endpoint**
[1234567890](common-pjsip-peer)
callerid=<1234567890>
auth=1234567890
aors=1234567890
[1234567890](common-webrtc-aor)
[1234567890](common-auth)
username=1234567890
password=4611
```